# respond_with returns unknown format - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using through `AngularJS` to send some json, in the controller I have

```
respond_to :json

def create
    respond_with Task.create(description: params[:description])
end
```

the `tasks` is stored on the database, but then I get this message in my log

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:372:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:327:in `respond_with'
```

...

I tried to add in my route `resources :tasks, :defaults => {:format => "js"}`. How can I handle this problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want your default format to be "json", not "js".

Rails has a list of formats that it is expecting (based on defaults plus you or gems can add additional known response types.) Js is not one of the defaults

Comment: how do you make it work with js? Is changing the defaults realistic?